Need help with checking a component
I need help with identifying this component. I'm trying to find a datasheet and I want to how to check if these functioning correctly.  The identification code on the chip are:
P0136SB
DM74ALS1034N


Hex driver? https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74als1034.pdf

This question does not show any research effort.

From a quick web search:
Part Number: DM74ALS1034N
Manufacturer:    onsemi
Category:Buffers, Drivers, Receivers, Transceivers
You find more details on the onsemi site or at www.snapeda.com

The manufacturer is Fairchild, not OnSemi.

@Justme Fairchild was bought by Onsemi.

In order to test if they are working as correctly, you can obtain a pinout of the integrated circuit (this is done usually by looking at the markings on the IC). This tells what pins are input, output, and power. If you cannot find the pinout, you can use a multimeter to check continuity for +V (positive volts) and gnd (0 volts/ground). Then you can check the continuity for the other ics that is near the ICs that you mentioned to check if the rest is input, output, or both (if the other ICs has a pin connected to the one of interest that is an output, that pin of the IC of interest is an input and vice versa). If you want to see if they work you can try to hook up switches to the inputs, resistors and leds to the outputs and a 5v power supply, or you can buy an 'ic tester'.

this is similar to the SN74ALS1034 IC which is a hex driver (buffer)
